# copy list items in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

Having a list as pbRecvBuffer=[112, 1, 0, 32, 225, 1, 0, 15, 55, 56, 52, 49, 57, 54, 57, 57, 56, 51, 55, 57, 56, 53, 49, 225, 2, 0, 9, 48, 54, 55, 51, 54, 50, 48, 54, 52, 0, 0, 0, 144, 0] in hexadecimal.
how can we copy the above items from index 8 to 0xf in  to another list.

My work on the above question.

```
iDataTagLength = ( pbRecvBuffer[index + 2] << 8 ) | pbRecvBuffer[index + 3]
```

where index = 4
and the resulting "iDataTagLength" i get is 0xf which is 15 in decimal.

```
PublicData['IDNumber']= pbRecvBuffer[(index + 4 ): iDataTagLength]
```

copying the above to public data results till "pbRecvBuffer[0Xf]" rather than copying 0XF items.

any help is appreciated and thankful in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the items to copy them to your desired variable. What you're getting here is a list reference. Printing the **class** will be helpful in future:

```
print (pbRecvBuffer[(index + 4 ): iDataTagLength]).__class__
```

This results in `<type 'list'>` as output.

Try iterating over the content of the list by using `(pbRecvBuffer[(index + 4 ): iDataTagLength][x]` where x is the index and populate the desired variable.